# Turning list of indices into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an `nxd` numpy array of zeros.  For every row in this array, I am tasked with converting a specified column to be a 1.  To this end, I have been given a list of size `n` such that the *ith* value of this list is the index to be turned into a 1.

This task can be accomplished via a `for` loop as below:

```
import numpy as np

N=5; D =3
array = np.zeros(shape=(N,D))
ones_index = [0,2,1,0,1]
for row, column in enumerate(ones_index):
    array[row,column] = 1
```

While this works just fine, I imagine that numpy has some function to achieve this above much more cleanly.  **Does there exist a numpy function that converts a list of indices into a certain values in an array?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```py
array = np.zeros(shape=(N, D))

ones_index = [0, 2, 1, 0, 1]
array[np.arange(N), ones_index] = 1

print(array)
```

Prints:

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
```

---

EDIT: Quick benchmark comparing this answer to Onaymbu's:

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot


def get_identity_andrej(N, D, ones_index):
    array = np.zeros(shape=(N, D))
    array[np.arange(N), ones_index] = 1
    return array


def get_identity_onyambu(N, D, ones_index):
    return np.identity(max(ones_index) + 1)[ones_index]


np.random.seed(0)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: (n * 5, n * 3, np.random.randint(0, n * 3, size=n * 5)),
    kernels=[
        get_identity_andrej,
        get_identity_onyambu,
    ],
    labels=["andrej", "onyambu"],
    n_range=[1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 100, 250, 500, 1000],
    xlabel="N",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=None,
)
```

On my computer (AMD 5700x) this gives me this result:

[image]

Comment: what i usually use for one hot encoding `np.identity(max(ones_index)+1)[ones_index]`

Comment: @Onyambu make it an other answer and I upvote it :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `np.identity`:

```
np.identity(max(ones_index) + 1)[ones_index]

array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.]])
```

Comment: I've added benchmark to my answer.